# Get element from Set

Tags: scala

How can I get element at position in Set ?

For a List can do  :

```
  val s : Set[(String, String)] = Set( ("a","b") )
  val l1 = l(0)
```

But for Set :

```
  val s : Set[(String, String)] = Set( ("a","b") )
  val t1 = s(1)
```

I get compile time error :

```
Multiple markers at this line - type mismatch; found : Int(1) required: (String, String) - type mismatch; found : 
 Int(1) required: (String, String)
```

Update :

converting to List is an option but I though should be able to access a element at position in Set

Comment: Could you convert to List first?

Comment: Converting to list is not an option?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Set` is not an ordered collection - you can't get element by index.

You could use `head` method to get single element from `Set` (it's not the first element, just some element).

You could also process all elements using `foreach` method:

```
for (s <- Set("a", "b")) println(s)
```

If you want to get all elements in some order you should convert `Set` to `Seq` using `toSeq` method like this:

```
val mySeq = mySet.toSeq
```

Comment: Put another way: "How can I get element at position in `Set`?" – There is no such thing as a "position" in a `Set`.